# Fitnesse trying to load "defaultPath" as assembly

Tags: fitnesse, fitsharp, fitnesse-slim

I am trying to specify a [custom converter to Slim](http://www.syterra.com/Slim/CustomTypeConverters.html) by specifying a [suite configuration](http://www.syterra.com/FitSharp/SuiteConfigurationFile.html).

When I manually append `?test` (the button doesn't appear for some reason), I get the following exception:

> __EXCEPTION__:System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Path\To\fitnesse\__defaultPath__'

Any idea why it would be trying to load "defaultPath" as an assembly from the current working directory?

Below is my suite configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<suiteConfig>
  <ApplicationUnderTest>
    <AddAssembly>C:\Path\To\TestsAssembly.dll</AddAssembly>
    <AddNamespace>Tests_Namespace</AddNamespace>
    <AddAssembly>C:\Path\To\fitSharp.dll</AddAssembly>
  </ApplicationUnderTest>

  <fitSharp.Machine.Application.Settings>
    <Runner>fitSharp.Slim.Service.Runner</Runner>
  </fitSharp.Machine.Application.Settings>

  <fitSharp.Slim.Service.Service>
    <AddOperator>NamespaceToConverter.NullableDecimalConverter</AddOperator>
  </fitSharp.Slim.Service.Service>

</suiteConfig>
```

My Fitnesse wiki page starts like this:

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {"%m" -c c:\Path\To\SlimConfig.xml %p}
!define TEST_RUNNER {C:\Path\To\fitsharp\Runner.exe}

|import|
... etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work around the problem by removing the classpath parameter (%p) from COMMAND_PATTERN:

```
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -c c:\Path\To\SlimConfig.xml}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have a !path, it defaults to 'defaultPath', so that's what was being passed as the %p parameter.  As you discovered, you should remove the %p if you don't have a !path.